# Are transaction cancellation reasons returned in the same order as the TransactWriteItemsRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

We are using the DynamoDB transaction API to perform 2 writes:

```
  TransactWriteItemsRequest transactionalWriteRequest = new TransactWriteItemsRequest();
  transactionalWriteRequest.withTransactItems(writeOne, writeTwo); 
  dynamoDB.transactWriteItems(transactionalWriteRequest);
```

If the transaction fails with a `TransactionCanceledException` we get back an exception with a list of `CancellationReason` objects.

In my scenario, imagine writeOne and writeTwo both fail. The exception will return two cancellation reasons.

My question is - does the ordering of those reasons match the ordering of the transactions in my request.

Is this always true?

```
 // Explains why writeOne failed
 transactionError.getCancellationReasons().get(0);
 // Explains why writeTwo failed
 transactionError.getCancellationReasons().get(1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs - yes, the ordering of cancellation reasons matches the order of transaction items: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html

> If using Java, DynamoDB lists the cancellation reasons on the
> CancellationReasons property. This property is not set for other
> languages. Transaction cancellation reasons are ordered in the order
> of requested items, if an item has no error it will have NONE code and
> Null message.